# How to add dependencies to java project automatically based on the import statements?

Tags: java, maven

I'm not familiar with using java package. Now I'm given a set of java files that import plenty of stuff. But there's no pom.xml file provided.

First I tried to directly compile the files, but was told `com.amazonaws is not found`. So I think I may need to download all the dependencies. But there are simply too many import statements so it seems not very practical to download them one by one manually.

Then I found that I may use maven. But after I tried creating this pom.xml

```
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
    <artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
    <version>1.11.341</version>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

and use `mvn package`. I got an error telling me building failed. I thought that might be because I didn't specify all the dependencies. Is there a way to automatically pull dependencies based on `import` statements in the java files?

Comment: Like @paulsm4 says, Maven can't just guess everything. But with so many import statements and yet no dependencies provided — can't you just ask or complain at the one who provided the Java files in the first place? Seems he should provide the dependencies along with the Java files. Unless this is a homework assignment or something...

Comment: @Patrick - got things working?  If not please 1) read the AWS/Maven setup link below, and 2) update your post with the current pom.xml and current mvn error(rs).

Comment: @paulsm4 Sorry for replying late. Thanks so much for the link! Helped a lot. I've not fully worked it out yet but is on the road. I indeed met another problem related to finding groupId and artifactId from the import statements, but I think maybe I should ask that in another question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maven is the right way to go. And you've made a good start.

Although Maven is very good about pulling "implicit dependencies", it can't "guess" everything. It sounds like you're going to have to add just a bit more to your pom.xml

SUGGESTIONS:

- Read this:

  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/setup-project-maven.html
- Post the specific errors you're getting with your current pom.xml.  Be sure to copy/paste the exact errors, along with updating the exact contents of the pom.xml that you used in that iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Using MVN is best approach to add dependencies to you project. You need to write some more stuff in your pom.xml . You can go through this example https://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html to create a maven project step by step